# Get rid of the question mark for php files?

Tags: .htaccess

Right now I have a url like this: `myurl.com/?u=b`. But I would like to get rid of the question mark and ideally even the `u=` so I would just be left with: `myurl.com/b` and I was wondering if this was at all possible with htaccess and how? Advance thanks.

Comment: Sure that is possible. And you will find hundreds of existing examples for that here on SO. Or elsewhere in the internet. A good idea also is to start reading the documentation of the rewriting module the apache http server brings along.

Comment: There is one question you need to answer prior to starting an implementation, though: I assume there are also other URLs published by your http server? Assuming you define a new URL `https://example.com/bbb` by means of internal rewriting. Then how can the server distinguish between such a URL that should internally get rewriiten to `?u=bbb` and any other URL that should _not_ get rewritten?

Comment: @arkascha that’s really not that a problem because I only have an index page at that path so I should not have any problems as long as I don’t have index as the u value, which I can check for fairly easy.

Comment: @arkascha I will read the documentation as I’ve been meaning to understand it better anyways thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no collisions with other URLs and your "index page", so your logic, can be referenced using the root path "/" on your service this looks pretty straight forward: you need a single rewriting rule:

```
Rewrite Engine on
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ /?u=$1 [QSA,END]
```

Such rule should get implemented in the http server's host configuration. If you do not have access to that you can use a distributed configuration file (often called ".htaccess"), but that comes with a performance penalty. The interpretation of such file has to be enabled first. Check that. Also the rewriting module needs to be enabled inside the http server, obviously.

If you have some file inside your http host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` where you implemented your logic then you may want to add a redirection to above rule ("index.php" is just an example here, obviously):

```
Rewrite Engine on
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php(?:/(.*))?$ /$1 [R=301,END]
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ /?u=$1 [END]
```

It might make sense to start out with a `R=302` *temporary* redirection and only change that to a `R=301` *permanent* redirection once you made sure everything works as desired. That prevents nasty caching issues.

Comment: Good answer with detailed explanations. +1 Arkascha.